# Will the constraints remain after Importing table from RDBMS to HIVE with sqoop?

Tags: sql, hive, sqoop, cloudera, rdbms

When we use `sqoop import` to transfer an RDBMS table to HIVE, will the **constraints** of the table such as **primary key**  remain ?

i.e. will the column of the table which is the **primary key** remain as primary  key at the `HIVE`. Will this information be in the Hive metastore ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the link of the official documentation of Hive QL below, PRIMARY and FOREIGN constraints have been added since Hive version 2.1.0.
[Hive QL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL)

[image: Hive 2.1.0 Changes]

So, I assume that the PRIMARY and FOREIGN Keys constraints will remain when you import your tables to Hive using sqoop.

I tested a sqoop import of MySQL database, and I can see that PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT is not maintained during the import.

MySQL Table Format:

```
    mysql> show create table employees;
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| employees | CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` date NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `gender` enum('M','F') NOT NULL,
  `hire_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Data has been imported from MySQL to Hive with the following command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees --username root --password password --table employees --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table employees
```

When I describe the table in hive, I cannot see the PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT

```
hive> show create table employees;
OK
CREATE TABLE `employees`(
  `emp_no` int, 
  `birth_date` string, 
  `first_name` string, 
  `last_name` string, 
  `gender` string, 
  `hire_date` string)
COMMENT 'Imported by sqoop on 2019/03/18 00:24:11'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'field.delim'='', 
  'line.delim'='\n', 
  'serialization.format'='') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/employees'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1552865076')
Time taken: 1.304 seconds, Fetched: 22 row(s)
```

I inserted a new row with same employee number to check if Hive manage PK Constraint. The new row has been added as you can see:

```
hive> insert into employees values (10001, "1986-04-17", "Hichem", 
"BOUSSETTA", "M", "2014-09-91");
Moving data to directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/employees/.hive-staging_hive_2019-03-18_00-32-16_851_8569619447966100947-1/-ext-10000
Loading data to table default.employees
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 5.79 sec   HDFS Read: 5080 HDFS Write: 120 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 5 seconds 790 msec
OK
Time taken: 42.422 seconds
hive> select * from employees;
OK
10001   1986-04-17  Hichem  BOUSSETTA   M   2014-09-91
10001   1953-09-02  Georgi  Facello M   1986-06-26
10002   1964-06-02  Bezalel Simmel  F   1985-11-21
```

So to conclude: **Sqoop does not preserve PK constraint when importing RDBMS data to Hive**

Comment: I think these constraints is applicable when you create a table through HIVE shell-command.  As you can see it's for  HIVE DDL statements. Please let me know when you verify it.

Comment: Yes right. I'll check this tomorrow. Hive is expected to be more and more compliant with standard sql. So, I think there is good chance it works when synchronizing data with rdbms

Comment: @eMazarakis I made the test today and have seen that sqoop does not import the primary key constraint. I will update my first answer